# Default and Custom Domains for GitHub Pages

Tags: html, web, github, dns, host

If you buy a custom domain to use for GitHub pages, will your old default GitHub domain still be reserved and accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, In fact your old Github provided subdomain is what gets mapped to your custom domain.

Comment: So, in the end, both domains will be accessible at the same time, right?